# Add query params to a GET request in okhttp in Android

Tags: android, okhttp

Is there a way to add query params (`?param1=val1&param2=val2`) to a GET request using `okhttp` in Android?

I am looking for an API and not manually adding the params in a loop and escaping the values.

Comment: add params to http entitiy.

Answer (score 14):

Try `HttpUrl` class (in `okhttp` package).

---

```
//adds the pre-encoded query parameter to this URL's query string
addEncodedQueryParameter(String encodedName, String encodedValue)

//encodes the query parameter using UTF-8 and adds it to this URL's query string
addQueryParameter(String name, String value)
```

Note: if there are already name/value pairs with this name, these functions will just add another pair

---

```
setEncodedQueryParameter(String encodedName, String encodedValue)

setQueryParameter(String name, String value)
```

Note: if there are already name/value pairs with this name, these functions will remove them and only after that add this new pair

---

Example:

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("https")
    .host("www.google.com")
    .addPathSegment("search")
    .addQueryParameter("q", "polar bears")
    .build();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [HttpUrl](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.html).

Say you already have a String url ready, just want to append the queries:

```
HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.parse("http://www.google.com/search").newBuilder()
   .addQueryParameter("q", "cat videos")
   .build();
```

For the details about query parameters, see Vitaly's answer, or refer to the [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the current version of okhttp, [there is no method provided that will handle this for you](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Request.Builder.html).

However, [Jesse Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40013/jesse-wilson), one of okhttp's developers, [has stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142626/how-to-add-query-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-by-okhttp/30143238#comment48395634_30143238) that

> We're adding a new HttpUrl class that can do this in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

```
val url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers/fee".toHttpUrlOrNull()?.newBuilder()
            ?.addQueryParameter("amount", "100")
            ?.addQueryParameter("currency", curr)
            ?.build()

 val request = url?.let {
        okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${HeaderBearerKey}")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .url(it)
            .build()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.net.Uri
var url = Uri.parse(urlWithoutQueryParams).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("key","value").build().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("https")
    .host("www.google.com")
    .addPathSegment("search")
    .addQueryParameter("q", "polar bears")
    .build();
System.out.println(url);
```

**output:**

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=polar%20bears
```

- Reference: [Okhttp HttpUrl](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-http-url/)