# How to add query parameters to a HTTP GET request by OkHttp?

Tags: java, http-get, okhttp, query-string

I am using the latest okhttp version: **okhttp-2.3.0.jar**

How to add query parameters to GET request in okhttp in java ?

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875325/add-query-params-to-a-get-request-in-okhttp-in-android) about android, but no answer here!

Comment: What's preventing you from simply including it into the URL? new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://publicobject.com?param1=value1&param2=value2")
        .build();

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, okhttp v2.4 offers new functionality that does make this possible.

See http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpUrl.Builder.html#addQueryParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

---

---

This is not possible with the current version of okhttp, [there is no method provided that will handle this for you](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Request.Builder.html).

The next best thing is building an url string or an `URL` object (found in `java.net.URL`) with the query included yourself, and pass that to the request builder of okhttp.

[image]

As you can see, the Request.Builder can take either a String or an URL.

Examples on how to build an url can be found at [What is the idiomatic way to compose a URL or URI in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883136/is-there-a-good-url-builder-for-java)

Comment: We're adding a new HttpUrl class that can do this in the next release.

Comment: @JesseWilson that is a nice improvemend :-)

Answer (score 89):

For okhttp3:

```
private static final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();

public static void get(String url, Map<String,String>params, Callback responseCallback) {
    HttpUrl.Builder httpBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(url).newBuilder();
    if (params != null) {
       for(Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {
           httpBuilder.addQueryParameter(param.getKey(),param.getValue());
       }
    }
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(httpBuilder.build()).build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(responseCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 30):

Here's my interceptor

```
    private static class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private String mApiKey;

    public AuthInterceptor(String apiKey) {
        mApiKey = apiKey;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        HttpUrl url = chain.request().url()
                .newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("api_key", mApiKey)
                .build();
        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I finally did my code, hope the following code can help you guys. I build the URL first using

> `HttpUrl httpUrl = new HttpUrl.Builder()`

Then pass the URL to `Request requesthttp` hope it helps .

```
public class NetActions {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public String getStudentById(String code) throws IOException, NullPointerException {

        HttpUrl httpUrl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
                .scheme("https")
                .host("subdomain.apiweb.com")
                .addPathSegment("api")
                .addPathSegment("v1")
                .addPathSegment("students")
                .addPathSegment(code) // <- 8873 code passthru parameter on method
                .addQueryParameter("auth_token", "71x23768234hgjwqguygqew")
                // Each addPathSegment separated add a / symbol to the final url
                // finally my Full URL is: 
                // https://subdomain.apiweb.com/api/v1/students/8873?auth_token=71x23768234hgjwqguygqew
                .build();

        System.out.println(httpUrl.toString());

        Request requesthttp = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
                .url(httpUrl) // <- Finally put httpUrl in here
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(requesthttp).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of right now (okhttp 2.4), HttpUrl.Builder now has methods addQueryParameter and addEncodedQueryParameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a newBuilder from existing HttoUrl and add query parameters there. Sample interceptor code:

```
    Request req = it.request()
    return chain.proceed(
        req.newBuilder()
            .url(
                req.url().newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("v", "5.60")
                .build());
    .build());
```

Answer (score 1):

One-line example:

```java
assert HttpUrl.parse("https://httpbin.org/get")
        .newBuilder()
        .addQueryParameter("hello", "world")
        .build()
        .equals("https://httpbin.org/get?hello=world");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpUrl class's functions:

```
//adds the pre-encoded query parameter to this URL's query string
addEncodedQueryParameter(String encodedName, String encodedValue)

//encodes the query parameter using UTF-8 and adds it to this URL's query string
addQueryParameter(String name, String value)
```

more detailed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32146909/5247331

Answer (score 0):

Beased on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/okhttp-android-example-tutorial

```
HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://example.COM/
/** we are creating a url*/
THE_API_PATH").newBuilder();

 /**Adding parameters*/
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("website", "www.example.com");
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("tutorials", "android");

/** building url and converting it to string */
String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();


/** creating request so we could give it to OkHTTP */
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                 .url(url)
                 .build();


OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
 client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
    Log.i("HTTP " ,  " " +  e.toString() );
    call.cancel();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

    final String myResponse = response.body().string();

    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Log.i("HTTP " , "Response it's :" + myResponse );
       /** this it's your Response to String 
        if you are using json , convert your string .
         better to not do that in main thread*/
      }
    });

  }
});
```