# How to make a GET Request using okhttp

Tags: android-networking

I am new to Android Development and I would like to know how to perform a GET request using `okhttp`. I have referred http://square.github.io/okhttp/, but they only have examples of POST request. I have tried this -

```
        okHttpClientLogin = new OkHttpClient();
        requestBodyLogin = new FormBody.Builder()
                .addEncoded("name", name_input) // params
                .addEncoded("keys", keys_input) //params
                .build();

        requestLogin = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", token_type + " " +access_token)
                .url(LOGIN_URL)
                .get()
                .build();
```

and got an Error :

> {"status":{"status":206,"msg":"No record found"},"user":null}

I know why this error is coming, because the params have not been entered. I also tried passing `requestBodyLogin` inside `.get()`  but it's not allowing.

Comment: "Please give a Solution for this problem." You may have not meant it this way, but this sounds bad in English, like a boss talking to his employee. You might want to rephrase or remove that line.

Comment: From the error it appears that the Get call in working, however your service end-point is throwing an application error. Add details like what parameters are required by the end-point.

Comment: For okhttp3, here is a solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43029045/1784529

Answer (score 1):

Since OkHTTP 2.4, there's the function `addQueryParameter`. You can either use a `HttpUrl`, a `String` or a `java.net.URL` as url.
Basically, just create a new `HttpUrl.Builder()` and use the function `addQueryParameter`.

Example taken from the javadocs:

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
       .scheme("https")
       .host("www.google.com")
       .addPathSegment("search")
       .addQueryParameter("q", "polar bears")
       .build();
```

http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.html

http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpUrl.Builder.html#addQueryParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-