# Correct syntax for adding parameters to get() and post() request using okhttp in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, okhttp

**What I want to achieve ?**

I am trying to send two parameters in my Server URL using OkHttp through both get and post bcoz i want to know the syntax for both the methods.

**What I had Tried ?**

I have searched SO for questions on OkHttp but those had not solved my IllegalArgumentException.

I have seen below links :

[Add query params to a GET request in okhttp in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875325/add-query-params-to-a-get-request-in-okhttp-in-android)

and this

[How to add parameters to api (http post) using okhttp library in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233632/how-to-add-parameters-to-api-http-post-using-okhttp-library-in-android)

and

[How to add query parameters to a HTTP GET request by OkHttp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142626/how-to-add-query-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-by-okhttp)

**Exception from code 2:**

[image]

**Code I had used till now :**

1)GET

```
   urls = chain.request().httpUrl() <-- NullPointerException Line
                    .newBuilder()
                    .scheme("http")
                    .host(SERVER_IP)
                    .addQueryParameter("from", valueFrom)
                    .addQueryParameter("to",valueTo)
                    .build();

        request = chain.request().newBuilder().url(urls).build();

        response = chain.proceed(request);
```

2)GET

```
     urls =new HttpUrl.Builder()
                    .host(SERVER_IP)  <--- IllegalArgumentException line
                    .addQueryParameter("from", valueFrom)
                    .addQueryParameter("to", valueTo)
                    .build();

            request = new Request.Builder().url(urls).build(); 

            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

3)POST

```
  body = new      
  MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM).addFormDataPart("from",
  valueFrom).addFormDataPart("to",valueTo).build();

        Log.i("Body data",""+body.toString());

        request = new Request.Builder().url(params[0]).post(body).build();

        Log.i("Request data",""+request.toString());

        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

4)POST

```
  body = new FormEncodingBuilder().add("from", valueFrom).add("to", 
  valueTo).build();

        Log.i("Body data",""+body.toString());

        request = new Request.Builder().url(params[0]).post(body).build();

        Log.i("Request data",""+request.toString());

        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

build.gradle

```
  dependencies 
  {
   compile files('libs/okhttp-2.5.0.jar')
   compile files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar')
  }
```

Thanks In Advance...

**Edit :**

The above code for POST request is working fine now

But for GET request I still have no solution.

Answer (score -2):

Just set your GET parameter extend your URL:

```
RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .add("requestParamName", requestParameter.getRequestParams())
                .build();


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://www.test.com/serviceTest?parama=abc&paramb=123")
                .post(body)
                .build();
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a GET request call ?